# git cherry-pick fails on Github Actions runner while succeeding locally

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I'm trying to create a Github Actions workflow that cherry-pick certain commits from pull requests to a special branch in my repo. The workflow is pretty simple: it clones the repository on a runner, creates a temporary branch and cherry-picks a given commit to the branch, it then makes a new PR to the special branch.

To test the workflow, I have set up 2 branches, `main` and `dev`. The commit graph is as follow:

```
c1 -- c2 -- c3 -- c4 
            ^dev   ^main
```

The graph is linear with `dev` being behind `main` by only 1 commit, `c4`. The way I understand git cherry-pick, I should be able to cherry-pick commit `c4` to `dev` without any issue. I confirmed this is the case by doing a cherry-pick locally. However, when running the same script on Github Actions, I always get a merge conflict. The diff shows that the changes in `c4` conflict with those in `c3`. How is this happening? Shouldn't git figure out that the parent of `c4` and the tip of `dev` are exactly the same commit and cherry-picking should go smoothly?

Comment: Probably you are not working on the same revisions (the one you have checked out and what you are cherry-picking) between both "environments". Can you make sure that the commits involved are the exact same? The crystal ball I keep over here says they won't be the same.

Comment: CI/CD pipelines are commonly just checking out a shallow clone with just the latest commit, I am quite certain that's the problem here.

Comment: You are correct @hlovdal. I didn't realize the checkout action I'm using is shadow cloning by default, so even simple merges failed. Changing that behaviour fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out the checkout action I was using is shallow cloning the repository by default (with `--depth=1`), so no commit history was available for merging to be possible. Changing the `depth` parameter when cloning fixed the issue for me.